# R function calculating statistic of variable column name

Tags: r

Sorry for the bad post to start...

I'm trying to do this:

```
function(pollutant)

##some code here

bad <- is.na(dataset$pollutant)
mean(dataset$pollutant[!bad])
```

Where

```
dataset <- read.csv(file, header=TRUE)
```

The file has multiple pollutants as column names. If I explicitly enter the pollutant name instead of the variable "pollutant" the code works.

For example:

```
function()

##some code here

bad <- is.na(dataset$CO2)
mean(dataset$CO2[!bad])
```

What is the correct syntax so I can have a variable pollutant name?

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking how to use a column name passed as an argument to a function??

```
myfunction <- function(df, col) mean(df[,col], na.rm=T)

# test
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
myfunction(df,"x")
# [1] 0.1322028
```

This also works if you pass a column number.

```
myfunction(df,1)
# [1] 0.1322028
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider avoiding writing a function and just use the `with` function in R

```
> DF
#   col1 pollutant
# 1    1         4
# 2    2         5
# 3    3        NA
# 4    4         7
# 5    5         8
# 6    6        NA

> with(DF, mean(pollutant, na.rm = TRUE))
# [1] 6
```

and

```
> with(DF, mean(col1, na.rm = TRUE))
# [1] 3.5
```

If you want a function, you can pass the column directly to the function,

```
f <- function(column){
    mean(column, na.rm = TRUE)
}

> f(DF[, 'pollutant'])
# [1] 6
```

Or even pass `na.rm` as an argument in your custom function arguments with `...`.  This makes it easier if you're making more than one calculation in your function that requires use of the same argument.

```
f2 <-function(column, ...){
    list(mean = mean(column, ...), 
         stDev = sd(column, ...), 
         var = var(column, ...))
}

> f2(DF[, 'pollutant'], na.rm = TRUE)
# $mean
# [1] 6

# $stDev
# [1] 1.825742

# $var
# [1] 3.333333
```